# Automated Testing of iOS 6 State Preservation and Restoration

Tags: ios, testing, uikit-state-preservation

I'm updating an app to use the new state preservation and restoration functionality in iOS 6. As far as I can tell the best guidance on testing this in apps involves doing it manually (e.g. http://www.absoluteripple.com/1/post/2012/09/ios-6-state-preservation-and-restoration.html ).

Are there any ways to do automated testing of preserving and restoring state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from manually running it as the link you provided specifies—or using something like the UI Automation instrument—your best bet is to test the integration points as units. Instead of testing the entire system, test the individual methods you implement to ensure they interact with UIKit properly. Otherwise, you’re just testing that Apple’s code behaves consistently.

For new OS versions, you’ll need to go in and test them holistically, but that’s much less often than, say, every commit.